How to find the charge gradient of a polarized wire?

How would I find the charge gradient or total charge on either side of the wire, given the application of an electrical field parallel to that wire, provided by, say, a negatively charge plate.

If I am not mistaken, one would need to solve this equation unless the problem has some kind of symmetry which can be exploited.
